# Conditional Compilation in Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, jvm

Coming from languages like C++ or Rust it's *extremely* nice to be able to have different behaviors depending on the build type, particularly for logging or assertions (debug build in-execution testing, where a warning can always fail and abort for example). In these languages we can do something like;

```cpp
#ifdef SOME_DEBUG_COMPILE_DEFINITION
#define DEBUG_LOG(msg) printf("Log: %s\n", msg);
#else
#define DEBUG_LOG(msg)
#endif
```

Or in Rust

```rust
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
fn foo(){
  // do debug stuff
}

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions)]
fn foo() {
  // do release stuff
}
```

Is there anything like this in Kotlin on Android? I can't seem to find any documentation about this. I certainly hope there is some as it would be a pretty big oversight to not have this as a language feature, particularly since using features like this makes development much smoother (and faster; much faster) and can give stronger guarantees.